# Как рисовать кистью в PyQT5?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Хочу написать программу, которая рисует кистью, на рабочем столе (чтобы видеть весь интерфейс операционной системы) и на непрозрачном фоне.
Сейчас у меня проект состоит из одного прозрачного окна, на котором имеется QLabel во все окно и играет роль фона. Также на главном окне есть объект QPixmap, собственно, на котором и происходит все рисование.
Проблема: когда QLabel почти прозрачным (background(0, 0, 0, 2), рисование на QPixmap происходит как положено, виден интерфейс и сам рисунок. Когда я закрашиваю QLabel цветом, и делаю его непрозрачным, рисунок на QPixmap исчезает, и рисования не происходит. А мне хочется, чтобы можно было рисовать на прозрачном окне, и видеть весь интерфейс операционной системы и на каком-либо фоне, играющего роль доски. Также хочется, чтобы можно было отключать режим рисования и управлять интерфейсом операционной системы и при этом рисунок был виден.
Как это реализовать правильно? Может у меня совсем неверный подход?

```
class Canvas(QMainWindow):
def __init__(self, desktop: QDesktopWidget):
    super().__init__()

    self.gui_init(desktop.width(), desktop.height())

    self.desktop: QDesktopWidget = desktop
    self.background = QLabel(self)
    self.background.setFixedSize(self.width(), self.height())
    self.background.setStyleSheet(stylesheets.CANVAS_HIDE)

    self.pixmap = QPixmap(self.width(), self.height())
    self.lastPoint = QPoint()

def gui_init(self, w: int, h: int):
    self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
    self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
    self.setFixedSize(w, h)
    self.move(0, 0)

def paintEvent(self, event):
    painter = QPainter(self)
    painter.drawPixmap(self.rect(), self.pixmap)

def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    self.lastPoint = event.pos()                           

def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
    painter = QPainter(self.pixmap)
    painter.setPen(QPen(QColor(255, 0, 0), 5, Qt.SolidLine, Qt.RoundCap, Qt.RoundJoin))
    painter.drawLine(self.lastPoint, event.pos())
    self.lastPoint = event.pos()
    self.update()

def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
    pass
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему и лучше объясните что вы хотите сделать и что у вас не получается.